# Excel: Can you open a single workbook in two windows?

Tags: excel

Working in a multi-monitor environments with many worksheets in a single book, by default, opening a workbook will direct you to an existing instance of the workbook.

Since tabs only orient well when your monitors are of the same size, is there a way to open multiple instances so each monitor can have its own arrangement of tabs and worksheets?

Comment: Thanks for down voting asking about something that basically cannot be done prior to Office 13

Answer (score 0):

You will have to open two instances of Microsoft Excel, so say when open Microsoft excel you will have book1 open in first windown and then open another instance of microsoft excel by double clicking on microsoft excel icon this will open Book2. Now you can move the windows in a split screen, so I mean you will have Book1 open in first monitor and Book2 open in second monitor. Now just drag and drop the excel files in whichever monitor you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you drop between windows, or are you dragging from a file instance into the program instance?

I have two people in my office that have been fiddling with this and haven't been able to come up with anything on their own.

Comment: You will have to drag a file instance into the program instance. You won't be able to drop between windows.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2013, at least, you can use the **New Window** button in the *View* ribbon (the upper-left button in the screenshot below) to open a duplicate window of the active workbook (so `File X` becomes `File X:1` and `File X:2`, as displayed in the title of the window). Both windows function just like a single window would in terms of editing, switching between tabs, etc.

[image: Screenshot of View ribbon]

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I was looking for, will upvote and accept when have a chance to test.

Comment: Tried it on user computer, the two windows operate in full sync.

Minimizing or moving the window keeps them locked together.

Otherwise, this seemed to be correct.  Is there a way to correct this behavior?

Also, they're looking for the behavior of being able to work on different worksheets between instances, your statement of them operating as a single window between tabs seems to contradict that desire.

Comment: I meant that both windows function like a single window would, yet _independently_. That's how this feature works on my machine. My guess is that (if you have Excel 2013) that there is a setting preventing this behavior (_perhaps_ [this](http://superuser.com/a/21604/458281) could help). Otherwise, I'm unfortunately not sure.

Comment: This sounds like it's on the right track, I'll push it to the new users.

Really not certain why it behaves the way it does in the user environment, though, the only thing that doesn't work in perfect sync between the windows is any window close operation, that only closes the single instance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this fundamentally cannot be done except in Office 13 (or later)